# Non-browser sent HTTP request and PHP sessions

Tags: php, http, session, client-side

Is PHP able to maintain a session with devices that aren't using a browser to communicate with the server?  I know that any application is capable of adhering  to the HTTP protocol, but for languages like Actionscript3 and Java that consist of HTTP request classes in their frameworks, do they send the necessary parameters for PHP to hold a session like it does with a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any HTTP client library *can* support cookies (which is how PHP maintains session token state across requests by default). Some will handle cookies automatically, some will require it to be turned on in a preference, some will just provide an API to access the headers (which include the cookies).

Comment: i was under the impression that sessions and cookies were two different things http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/session_cookie.htm, im ideally looking at using only the session_start() process, since im not building a shopping cart or anything that requires long term states.

Comment: A session is a packet of data stored of the server that is associated with an identifying token which the browser sends to the server with each request. Most implementations of sessions, including PHP's default one, use a cookie to pass that token between the client and the server.